# Generic type to replace all keys of an object with a mapping

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a generic type to replace all keys of an object type with a mapping.

Let says we have :

```
type Input = {
  foo: string
  bar: string
}
```

And a mapping :

```
enum Mapping {
  foo = "foo2",
  bar = "bar2",
  otherkey = "otherkey2,
  ....lots of other properties
}
```

I would like a generic type `GenericType` so that `GenericType<Input>` is equal to:

```
{
  foo2: string
  bar2: string
}
```

And if possible, I would like to be recursive so that the objects inside Input are also remapped.

Could you help me doing that? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapping utility like `MapKeys` below:

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmA0hEBnAPAKClZJ5hQQAewEAdgCapQBKEAxgPYBOl6qwLAluQOYAaKJx78AfAOxQAKkVIVqdRq3YjegqAFdyAa3JMA7uQmYxUALxQA3lIDaiKLyg6UTAGYyocGg5JkqNC4g7rgoBFAA-KH4CPYAulAAXLhxiVI40vFy-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)

```ts
type MapKeys<
  KeyMap extends Record<string, string>,
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof KeyMap ? KeyMap[K] : K]:
    T[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
      ? MapKeys<KeyMap, T[K]>
      : T[K];
};

type Input = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
};

const keyMap = {
  foo: 'foo2',
  bar: 'bar2',
} as const;

type KeyMap = typeof keyMap;
type Output = MapKeys<KeyMap, Input>; /*
{
  foo2: string;
  bar2: string;
  baz: string; // Key wasn't in the map, so not modified
}
*/

type InputNested = {
  foo: string;
  bar: {
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
    baz: number;
  };
  baz: string;
};

type OutputNested = MapKeys<KeyMap, InputNested>; /*
{
  foo2: string;
  bar2: {
    foo2: number;
    bar2: number;
    baz: number; // Key wasn't in the map, so not modified
  };
  baz: string;
}
*/


// And if you want to use an enum (but I suggest that you don't):

enum KeyMap2 {
  foo = 'foo2',
  bar = 'bar2',
}

type Output2 = MapKeys<typeof KeyMap2, Input>; /*
                       ^^^^^^
Use "typeof" to get the type of the enum itself */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the shortest possible way, its:

```
type Genetic<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof typeof Mapping ? typeof Mapping[K] : K]: T[K];
};

type Foo = Genetic<Input>;
```

- `as` let's you remap the type into some other type
- as supports extends to become conditional to check existence